# freeing the memory while using glist from glib in c gives memory read/write error in calling function

Tags: c, memory-management, glib

I have a project that has a calling function as

```
void process_message(char *dev_ip, json_t *dev_config, char* message, json_t *extra_info, long col_ts, long log_counter, char *client_id, int unique_id)
{
......
 char *encoded_msg;
        //g_mutex_lock(&mutex_encode);
        //encoded_msg = get_encoded_msg(message, charset);
        //g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_encode);
        encoded_msg = message;
        if(encoded_msg == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
          //note the function here////
        GSList *parsed_msg = LineParser(dev_ip, encoded_msg, "\n", file_path, unique_id);  //get list of parsed message
        zlog_debug(c, "Number of parsed msg: %d", g_slist_length(parsed_msg));
        GSList *iterator = NULL;
        for (iterator = parsed_msg; iterator; iterator = iterator->next) 
        {
             //memory read error if freed in another function///
            zlog_debug(c, "Current item is '%s'\n", iterator->data);

            char *encoded_single_msg = (char *)iterator->data;

        }


}
```

than i have the function LineParser as

```
GSList *LineParser(char* dev_ip, char *msg_full, char *separator, char *file_path, int unique_id)
{
    GSList *parsed_msg = NULL;
    char connection_id[50];
    sprintf(connection_id,"%s|%d", dev_ip, unique_id);
    char *msg_concat;


    // inserting {file_path : last_not_complete_line} logic to TCP_CACHE
    //and removing the correspoing last_line
    g_mutex_lock (&mutex_hash_main);

    // char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup((GHashTable *) g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id), file_path));

    GHashTable *t_filepath_msg_dict = NULL;         //for {file_path : last_not_complete_line}
    if (TCP_CACHE != NULL)
    {
        t_filepath_msg_dict = (GHashTable *)(g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id));
        if (t_filepath_msg_dict != NULL)
        {
            char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path));

            if(last_line != NULL)   //if the hash has device ip, append the value to msg
            {
                zlog_debug(c,"concatenating: str1: %s and str2: %s\n", last_line, msg_full);

                 ////note the asprintf which is to be freed
                asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", last_line, msg_full);
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);
                msg_full = msg_concat;
                free(msg_concat);
            }   
        }

    }


    int msg_len = strlen(msg_full);
    char last_char = msg_full[msg_len - 1];
    zlog_debug(c, "len of message: %d", msg_len);
    zlog_debug(c, "last char is : %c", last_char);
    char *token=NULL;
    char *remaining_str=NULL;
    token = strtok_r(msg_full, "\n", &remaining_str);

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(token[0]==' ')
        {
            token = trimwhitespace_parser (token);
            if(strcmp(token,"")==0)
            {
                //insert this token to GSList
                parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (parsed_msg, token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(strcmp(remaining_str,"")==0)
        {
            if(strlen(token) > 10000)
            {
                zlog_warn(c, "Message too big(more than 10000 len). Stop looking for new line and process msg");
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);
            }
            else
            {
                if(last_char=='\n')
                {
                    //new line is the last character. do nothing
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is new line");
                }
                else
                {
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is not new line");
                    //new line not received
                    if (t_filepath_msg_dict == NULL)        //insert new record
                    {
                        GHashTable *each_filepath_msg_dict = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, key_str_destroy_cb_parser, value_str_destroy_cb_parser);
                        zlog_debug(c,"Inserting file_path: %s to connection_id: %s", file_path, connection_id);

                        g_hash_table_insert(each_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                        g_hash_table_insert(TCP_CACHE, strdup(connection_id), each_filepath_msg_dict);
                    }
                    else        //update existing record
                    {
                        zlog_debug(c,"Connection_id :%s is already found; appending/replacing file_path :%s", connection_id, file_path);
                        g_hash_table_insert(t_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                    }
                    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
                    return parsed_msg;
                }
            }
        }
        //insert token to GSList
        parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (parsed_msg, token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
    }
    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
    return parsed_msg;
}
```

here in the code I have the asprint as
**asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", last_line, msg_full);**

this msg_concat needs to be freed to reduce memory leak. however when I used free(msg_concat) at the end . I cannot properly free the memory and gives me error that **memory read error** at the **process_message** at

```
**for (iterator = parsed_msg; iterator; iterator = iterator->next) 
            {
                zlog_debug(c, "Current item is '%s'\n", iterator->data);

                char *encoded_single_msg = (char *)iterator->data;

            }**
```

how can i free the msg_concat properly in the LineParser function without getting memory read error at the  process_message function??

Do the list returning the pointer points to the same address of the msg_concat to the calling function thus cannot be freed in the same LineParser function?

EDIT:
I have tried to pass the list as reference and return the msg_concat as:

```
GSList *parsed_msg=NULL;
          char *msg_concat = LineParser(dev_ip, encoded_msg, "\n", file_path, unique_id,&parsed_msg);  //get list of parsed message

        zlog_debug(c, "Number of parsed msg: %d", g_slist_length(parsed_msg));
        GSList *iterator = NULL;
        for (iterator = parsed_msg; iterator; iterator = iterator->next) 
        {
            zlog_debug(c, "Current item is '%s'\n", iterator->data);

            char *encoded_single_msg = (char *)iterator->data;


            json_object_set_new(extra_info, "client_id", json_string(client_id));
            // json_object_set_new(extra_info, "parser", json_string(parser));

#ifdef DEBUG
    char *extra_info_st;
    extra_info_st = json_dumps(extra_info, JSON_INDENT(4));
    zlog_debug(c,"extra_info_st msg is: %s\n", extra_info_st);
    int num_of_fields_after = json_object_size(extra_info);
    zlog_debug(c,"extra size is : %d\n", num_of_fields_after);
    free(extra_info_st);
#endif

            event = create_json_object(lp_name, extra_info, encoded_single_msg, dev_ip, dev_config, mid, col_ts, col_type, log_counter);

            /* send message to upper layer */
            send_event_with_mid(sender, event, normalizer, repo);

            //    AFREE(mid);
            json_decref(event);
            // AFREE(encoded_single_msg);
        }
        //json_decref(extra_info);
        free(msg_concat);
        g_slist_free(parsed_msg);
    }
```

and i re wrote the LineParser to return the msg_concat as:

```
char *LineParser(char* dev_ip, char *msg_full, char *separator, char *file_path, int unique_id, GSList **parsed_msg)
{
    //GSList *parsed_msg = NULL;
    char connection_id[50];
    sprintf(connection_id,"%s|%d", dev_ip, unique_id);
    char *msg_concat;


    // inserting {file_path : last_not_complete_line} logic to TCP_CACHE
    //and removing the correspoing last_line
    g_mutex_lock (&mutex_hash_main);

    // char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup((GHashTable *) g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id), file_path));

    GHashTable *t_filepath_msg_dict = NULL;         //for {file_path : last_not_complete_line}
    if (TCP_CACHE != NULL)
    {
        t_filepath_msg_dict = (GHashTable *)(g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id));
        if (t_filepath_msg_dict != NULL)
        {
            char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path));

            if(last_line != NULL)   //if the hash has device ip, append the value to msg
            {
                zlog_debug(c,"concatenating: str1: %s and str2: %s\n", last_line, msg_full);
                asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", last_line, msg_full);
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);
                msg_full = msg_concat;

            }   
        }

    }


    int msg_len = strlen(msg_full);
    char last_char = msg_full[msg_len - 1];
    zlog_debug(c, "len of message: %d", msg_len);
    zlog_debug(c, "last char is : %c", last_char);
    char *token=NULL;
    char *remaining_str=NULL;
    token = strtok_r(msg_full, "\n", &remaining_str);

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(token[0]==' ')
        {
            token = trimwhitespace_parser (token);
            if(strcmp(token,"")==0)
            {
                //insert this token to GSList
                *parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (*parsed_msg, token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(strcmp(remaining_str,"")==0)
        {
            if(strlen(token) > 10000)
            {
                zlog_warn(c, "Message too big(more than 10000 len). Stop looking for new line and process msg");
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);
            }
            else
            {
                if(last_char=='\n')
                {
                    //new line is the last character. do nothing
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is new line");
                }
                else
                {
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is not new line");
                    //new line not received
                    if (t_filepath_msg_dict == NULL)        //insert new record
                    {
                        GHashTable *each_filepath_msg_dict = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, key_str_destroy_cb_parser, value_str_destroy_cb_parser);
                        zlog_debug(c,"Inserting file_path: %s to connection_id: %s", file_path, connection_id);

                        g_hash_table_insert(each_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                        g_hash_table_insert(TCP_CACHE, strdup(connection_id), each_filepath_msg_dict);
                    }
                    else        //update existing record
                    {
                        zlog_debug(c,"Connection_id :%s is already found; appending/replacing file_path :%s", connection_id, file_path);
                        g_hash_table_insert(t_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                    }
                    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
                    return msg_concat;
                }
            }
        }
        //insert token to GSList
        *parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (*parsed_msg, token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
    }
    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
    return msg_concat;
}
```

however freeing msg_concat after returning and manupulation of list gives invalid free by valgrind;

Comment: You make the assignment ... msg_full = msg_concat; and then free(msg_concat); .  But then a few lines later you are using msg_full even though the memory it points to has been freed.

Comment: @JohnSheridan even I free the msg_concat at the end , the list returned cannot be read in the calling function with memory read /write error

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code and making minimal changes to deal with the specific memory management issue.  There may be other issues in your code.  I've not checked.

```
GSList *LineParser(char* dev_ip, char *msg_full, char *separator, char *file_path, int unique_id)
{
    GSList *parsed_msg = NULL;
    char connection_id[50];
    sprintf(connection_id,"%s|%d", dev_ip, unique_id);
    char *msg_concat = NULL;            //Initialize!!!


    // inserting {file_path : last_not_complete_line} logic to TCP_CACHE
    //and removing the correspoing last_line
    g_mutex_lock (&mutex_hash_main);

    // char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup((GHashTable *) g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id), file_path));

    GHashTable *t_filepath_msg_dict = NULL;         //for {file_path : last_not_complete_line}
    if (TCP_CACHE != NULL)
    {
        t_filepath_msg_dict = (GHashTable *)(g_hash_table_lookup(TCP_CACHE, connection_id));
        if (t_filepath_msg_dict != NULL)
        {
            char *last_line = (char *) (g_hash_table_lookup(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path));

            if(last_line != NULL)   //if the hash has device ip, append the value to msg
            {
                zlog_debug(c,"concatenating: str1: %s and str2: %s\n", last_line, msg_full);

                 ////note the asprintf which is to be freed
                asprintf(&msg_concat,"%s%s", last_line, msg_full);
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);
                msg_full = msg_concat;
                //free(msg_concat);    //Not safe to free here!
            }   
        }

    }


    int msg_len = strlen(msg_full);
    char last_char = msg_full[msg_len - 1];
    zlog_debug(c, "len of message: %d", msg_len);
    zlog_debug(c, "last char is : %c", last_char);
    char *token=NULL;
    char *remaining_str=NULL;
    token = strtok_r(msg_full, "\n", &remaining_str);

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(token[0]==' ')
        {
            token = trimwhitespace_parser (token);
            if(strcmp(token,"")==0)
            {
                //insert this token to GSList
                parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (parsed_msg, token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(strcmp(remaining_str,"")==0)
        {
            if(strlen(token) > 10000)
            {
                zlog_warn(c, "Message too big(more than 10000 len). Stop looking for new line and process msg");
                g_hash_table_remove(t_filepath_msg_dict, file_path);
            }
            else
            {
                if(last_char=='\n')
                {
                    //new line is the last character. do nothing
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is new line");
                }
                else
                {
                    zlog_debug(c, "last character is not new line");
                    //new line not received
                    if (t_filepath_msg_dict == NULL)        //insert new record
                    {
                        GHashTable *each_filepath_msg_dict = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, key_str_destroy_cb_parser, value_str_destroy_cb_parser);
                        zlog_debug(c,"Inserting file_path: %s to connection_id: %s", file_path, connection_id);

                        g_hash_table_insert(each_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                        g_hash_table_insert(TCP_CACHE, strdup(connection_id), each_filepath_msg_dict);
                    }
                    else        //update existing record
                    {
                        zlog_debug(c,"Connection_id :%s is already found; appending/replacing file_path :%s", connection_id, file_path);
                        g_hash_table_insert(t_filepath_msg_dict, strdup(file_path), strdup(token));
                    }
                    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
                    //If memory has been allocated then free it before returning.
                    if(msg_concat)
                        free(msg_concat);
                    return parsed_msg;
                }
            }
        }
        //insert token to GSList
        parsed_msg = g_slist_prepend (parsed_msg, token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remaining_str);
    }
    g_mutex_unlock(&mutex_hash_main);
    //Same here.  If memory has been allocated then free it before returning.
    if(msg_concat)
        free(msg_concat);
    return parsed_msg;
}
```

The other issue you are likely running into is that the memory pointed to by "token" is a subset of the string pointed to by msg_concat.  If you are going to add these to a list or hash table that will persist beyond the life of the LineParser function then you should be allocating new arrays and copying from "token" into the new char arrays.  You should then also deal with freeing the allocated arrays when the lists or hash tables are going out of scope.

EDIT ...

You have two options.  One involves significant restructuring of your LineParser function to deal with the issues already discussed.  There are complicating factors that you would also have to deal with.  For example, your "trimwhitespace_parser" function which I don't have visibility of would have to remove any leading whitespace by moving the contents of the array so that the first non-whitespace character is in the first position of the array.  This is because you will later want to free this memory, and if you return an offset from the original allocated memory then you're in trouble.  Each time you make a call to strtok_r and get a non NULL response you would have to allocate a char array of large enough size into which you would then copy the string returned by strtok_r.  You could use the asprintf function to do this as you already do in your code.  You then work with the array that you have allocated rather than token.  And as I mentioned already, none of your processing should cause you to lose / overwrite the original pointer value with one that is an offset from the original.  If that happens you won't be able to free it later.  Also your calling function needs to assume responsibility for freeing all of the items in the returned list.

The second option is fairly simple, but not elegant by any means.  If involves modifying the prototype of the LineParser function to take an additional char** parameter.  The idea is that you would assign msg_concat to that so that it is "returned" to the calling function.  The calling function then assumes responsibility for freeing it.  So your calling function would declare a char *ptr = NULL, and then pass that as &ptr when calling LineParser.  On return from LineParser, and only after you have finished with all usage of the linked list, etc, you would free(ptr) to clean up.

Comment: yes, I suppose that the token is a subset of msg_concat thus the msg_concat persiste even beyond the LineParser which I cannot free .  but how do i create char array to hold the list data??

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain your options as I see them.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I have once tried to pass the list by reference and return msg_concat as char *msg_concat = LineParser(dev_ip, encoded_msg, "\n", file_path, unique_id,&parsed_msg);    and later tried to free the returned msg_concat . however freeing msgconcat after list manupulation gives invalid free/delete by valgrind

Comment: Can you show me that code?  It's impossible to give meaningful comment without seeing it.  You could add it to the bottom of your original question and entitle it "Other things I've tried" or something similar.

Comment: I have added the updated pass by reference list code above in the question

Comment: Ok.  Have you tried commenting out all of your processing after the call to LineParser except for freeing the list and the msg_concat.  This would help isolate the allocation and free operations so that we can rule out any other cause.